Was there experimental data underlying Einstein's $E=mc^2$?
It is customary to provide formulas to describe experimental data, namely in regression.
So, when Einstein proposed the formula $E = mc^2$ (I reckon the original formulation was not like this, but I am not a physicist so I will stick to this 'canonical' formulation), did he want to provide a theoretical model to experimental data?
In other words, did Einstein produce this equation based on experimental data or was it a totally theoretical approach? And if the first case, what experimental data he used?
Thank you

The formula was proposed on purely theoretical grounds, as a consequence of special relativity.

It was a prediction from the theory. Confirmation of its validity came with radioactivity and particle physics.

This fourth annus mirabilis paper’s main result was born out of theory, unlike the photoelectric effect, Brownian motion, or the (negative) results of Michelson-Morley!
